# How to setup meld as merge tool on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 15.10, git

**EDIT:** `gitkraken` now features a merge tool with conflict resolution. Its available from the official gitkraken website. So I have a working solution

---

I am using `gitkraken` as my GUI-git client, which doesn't have an internal merge tool, so I am required to use `meld` as merge tool.

When I run `meld` in my terminal it works just fine.

However when I need to resolve a merge conflict in `gitkraken` it fails to open the tool, saying that the tool was not found; so I suspect I setup the `.gitconfig` wrong.

Here you can find part of my `.gitconfig`:

```
[merge]
    tool = meld
[diff]
    tool = meld
```

both set up with:

```
git config --global merge.tool
```

and

```
git config --global diff.tool
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be old but I'll contribute with my answer anyway. I had the same issue as you and I could solve it by providing this configuration:

```
    [diff]
        tool = meld
    [merge]
        tool = meld    
    [difftool "meld"]
        cmd = meld "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

So I think that the difference between your issue and mine is that you may be missing the command line specification.

Answer (score 1):

For the ppl who still want to use external merging tool,

Once you see a merge conflict in gitkraken just go to the terminal (in your project root folder) and type `git mergetool`. this will try to open the default merge tool configured.

Once merging is done, you can go back to gitkraken and `commit and merge` the changes.